# spark filter with higher order function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I get a higher order function in Scala to properly accept a spark filter predicate? 
I.e.

```
val df = Seq(1,2,3,4).toDF("value")

df.filter(col("value")> 2).show
df.filter(col("value")< 2).show
```

works just fine. But when I try to refactor it into a function which accepts a filter predicate (note: same signature as `>` operator) the compiler no longer finds the left/right part to submit to predicate.

```
def myFilter =(predicate:Any =>Column)(df:DataFrame)= {
df.filter(col("value") predicate 2).show // WARN this does not compile
}

df.transform(myFilter(>)).show
```

How can this be made to work?

Comment: In Scala `a x b` means `a.x(b)`, so `col("value") predicate 2` means `col("value").predicate(2)` which is not what you want. Perhaps something more like `predicate(col("value"), 2)`?

Comment: no, this is still not enough. `df.filter(col("value").predicate(2))` also does not work.

Comment: You need to change it to `predicate(col("value"), 2)`. You also need to change the signature of `predicate`. I don't know enough about Spark to give the full answer (which is why I am using comments) but it should be something like `(Column, Int) => Boolean`. Then you pass `_ > _` rather than just `>` to `myFilter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the various comments gives this as a possible solution:

```
def myFilter = (predicate: (Column, Int) => Column)(df: DataFrame) = {
  df.filter(predicate(col("value"), 2))
}

df.transform(myFilter(_ > _)).show
```