# Pyspark RDD - both filtered and unfiltered data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I created an RDD from spark session. My data is in syslog format. I wanted to filtered the rows that has prefix <128>1 as valid rows and the ones that does not satisfy the condition into invalid rows.

```
rdd2=rdd1.filter(lambda rec: rec.startswith('<128>1') or rec.startswith('<134>1'))
```

How do I get the invalid rows as well in the same function?
Reference: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter/
[spark filter with higher order function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440101/spark-filter-with-higher-order-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the negation (`not`) of the valid condition:

```
valid = rdd1.filter(lambda rec: rec.startswith('<128>1') or rec.startswith('<134>1'))
invalid = rdd1.filter(lambda rec: not(rec.startswith('<128>1') or rec.startswith('<134>1')))
```